# Is there any way to check the DOM element every few seconds in content.js in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am manipulating the DOM from my content.js in chrome extension. The webpage would be changed after an uncertain time. I would like to write some codes to monitor the change. That means I would like to do something after I found the DOM changed. Is there any way to check the DOM every few time or seconds in content.js? I have not done this before. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I think you're after a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you very much for relating this function, which I have never heard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way not so elegant like MutationObserver is to use setInterval to execute code periodically:

```
setInterval(()=> {
 let d = document.querySelector('#el')
 if(d){
  console.log('dom manipulation')
 }
},100)
```

Every 100 ms the function is executed.

To stop the interval, you have to save the return of setInterval to a variable. You pass this value to the global function clearInterval to stop the interval:

```
let interval = null

let domWorks = () => {
     let d = document.querySelector('#el')
     if(d){
      console.log('dom manipulation')
      clearInterval(interval) // Change it via reference
     }
}

interval = setInterval(domWorks, 100)
```

You can create a function that encapsulates the interval and execute some callback when some condition is true:

```
  const executeWhenItsReady = (testCondition, callbackToExecute) => {
      let interval = null;
      let tryToExecute = () => {
        let result = testCondition();
        console.log("trying again");
        if (result) {
          callbackToExecute();
          clearInterval(interval); // Change it via reference
        }
      };

      interval = setInterval(tryToExecute, 100);
    };

  executeWhenItsReady(
         () => document.querySelector("el"), 
         () => console.log("dom manipulation")
  );
```

Comment: Could you show me how to break the loop when the change happens? Need I using a "break"?

Comment: I will increment the answer to show how you can do this